# Change animate value onkeydown

Tags: jquery

I have this script:

```
var speed = 10;
 if(left && !right){ // Move siteA
        $(siteA).animate({'left':'+=10'}, 0);
     }
 if(right && !left){
        $(siteA).animate({'left':'-=10'}, 0);
     }
 if(up && !down){
        $(siteA).animate({'top':'+=10'}, 0);
     }
 if(down && !up){
        $(siteA).animate({'top':'-=10'}, 0);
     }
```

I want the "10" to actually be replaced with the variable speed. So I can change it at will. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate your string:

```
var increment = 10;
$(siteA).animate({'left':'+=' + increment}, 0);
```